# Angular 2 - Validators are getting set to false too fast

Tags: validation, angular, angular2-changedetection

I have 2 fields that get validated.
The issue is these fields are getting set with values by Chrome, such as the saved password and email.

So when the page loads the 2 fields (email + password) which have the right values as set via Chrome but the 2nd field is shown as invalid.

I am trying to detect changes after the page has loaded.

I have tried calling the changeDetectorRef from ngInit but it did not work.

When I click on the page the field then shows that it is valid.

Within the constructor:

```
 this.form = fb.group({
    'email': ['', Validators.compose([
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(4),
      EmailValidator.validate])],
    'password': ['', Validators.compose([
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(6)])]
  });

  this.email = this.form.controls['email'];
  this.password = this.form.controls['password'];
```

I have tried:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.zone.run(() => {
      this.email.updateValueAndValidity();
      this.password.updateValueAndValidity();
    });
}
```

But still no good.

I find it odd that the first field is shown as valid but the 2nd one is not.
It is a password field so that might have something to do with it?

Both fields are of type AbstractControl.

Here is the html:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group row" [ngClass]="{'has-error': (!email.valid), 'has-success': (email.valid)}">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>

    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input [formControl]="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row" [ngClass]="{'has-error': (!password.valid), 'has-success': (password.valid)}">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>

    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input [formControl]="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-10">
      <button [disabled]="!form.valid" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-auth">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: [This post](http://victorblog.com/2014/01/12/fixing-autocomplete-autofill-on-angularjs-form-submit/) mentions a fix for your problem. It applies to AngularJS but you could easily update the code for Angular 2+. The idea is to manually trigger a series of DOM events on the auto-completed fields when the form is submitted. In the article, he triggers 'input', 'change', and 'keydown' on all 'input', 'textarea', and 'select' tags found within the form. Side note: I'm not sure you need to trigger ALL those events; just one should be enough to kick off change detection.